# Python athena query

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-athena, pyathena

How many queries can execute python athena in one secound.I'm using python pyathena library.

```py
athena_cursor = connect(aws_access_key_id=CREDENTIALS_DICTIONARY['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
                        aws_secret_access_key=CREDENTIALS_DICTIONARY['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
                        s3_staging_dir=CREDENTIALS_DICTIONARY['S3_STAGING_DIR'],
                        region_name=CREDENTIALS_DICTIONARY['REGION_NAME'],
                        cursor_class=AsyncCursor).cursor()

query_id, future = athena_cursor.execute(query, query_dict)
result_set = future.result()
logging.warning("[{}] [ATHENA] [QUERY] [END] [{}]".format(datetime.now(), query))
results = result_set.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per AWS Athena documentation on [service limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html)

> You can make up to 20 `StartQueryExecution` calls per second. In addition, if this API is not called for 4 seconds, your account accumulates a burst capacity of up to 80 calls. In this case, your application can make up to 80 calls to this API in burst mode.

Although you can contact AWS Support to request a limit increase.